# Getting error while trying to get title from structure

Tags: javascript, html, data-structures

i need help, i am getting this error while trying to get title from structure, i don't know how to fix it.

This code works just fine.

```js
    function addCard(x,who) {
    
      if(who === 'player'){
        const  element = document.querySelector(".playercards");
        element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<button id='${x}' class='cardbutton'><p>${deck[x].title}</br></br>Action: ${deck[x].points} ${deck[x].action}</p></button>`);
      }
      if(who === 'bot'){
        const  element = document.querySelector(".botcards");
        element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<button id='bot${x}' class='cardbutton'><p>${deck[x].title}</br></br>Action: ${deck[x].points} ${deck[x].action}</p></button>`);
      }
    }
    
    playerCards.forEach((node, position) => addCard(node.getValue(),'player'));
    botCards.forEach((node, position) => addCard(node.getValue(),'bot'));
```

But this error happens when i use this code `deck[cardId].title`
It doesn't work, i dont know why, i have tried to put just a number like this `deck[1].title` but it still gets me an error. What problem it could be?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
    at HTMLUListElement.clickedOnCard (gamescript.js:47)
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEXxL.png)

47 line is

```
    console.log(deck[cardId].title())
```

```
    const deck = [
      {id: 0, title: 'Šokoladas', action: 'heal', points: 5},
      {id: 1, title: 'Sausainis', action: 'heal', points: 2},
      {id: 2, title: 'Pulti', action: 'damage', points: 3},
      {id: 3, title: 'Saukstas', action: 'damage', points: 1}
    ]

    document.querySelector(".playercards").addEventListener("click",clickedOnCard, false);
    
    function clickedOnCard(e) {
      if(e.target !== e.currentTarget){
        var cardId = e.target.id || e.srcElement.id;
        
        console.log(deck[cardId].title)
    
    
        // Deletes clicked player card
        removeCard(cardId);
    
        // Removes bot card
        removeCard(`bot${botCards.tail().getValue()}`);
        botCards.removeLast();
    
        updateHp();
    
        e.stopPropagation();
    
        postlog(getDate() + " Game: Button clicked." + " Used: " + cardId);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate your array to get your item, please use find

Comment: I am just trying to get id from html element (button) `document.querySelector(".playercards").addEventListener("click",clickedOnCard, false);`

Comment: codeSandboxwould be more helpful, it seems not clear much

Comment: This is whole my code, i don't know how to use codeSandbox, sorry https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-darkness-dcvok?file=/gamescript.js